Screen and mouse freeze after entering password
Not sure what I did wrong except having the laptop closed for a couple days without powering off. On going back to it the machine stopped working after I entered my password. Screen and mouse freeze. Last thing I did before closing it was running some updates that the system requested. This machine only has Ubuntu installed. Not sure what version I have since I can’t login to look. Needless to say I’m not an expert.

Have you tried turning it off and on again?
